# Ошибка 'exit' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c, unix

Программа, которая выдает размер директории. Выдает ошибку в строчке `exit (1). " 'exit' was not declared in this scope"`. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

main()
{
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *de;
  struct stat buf;
  int exists;
  int total_size;

  d = opendir(".");
  if (d == NULL) {
    perror("prsize");
    exit(1); // **ОШИБКА**
  }

  total_size = 0;

  for (de = readdir(d); de != NULL; de = readdir(d)) {
    exists = stat(de->d_name, &buf);
    if (exists < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't stat %s\n", de->d_name);
    } else {
      total_size += buf.st_size;
    }
  }
  closedir(d);
  printf("%d\n", total_size);
}
```

Comment: Плюс к ответу - что вернёт `stat()` на каталог? А на `.` или `..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчёт гугла я не стал бы рекомендовать. За то, что там выдаст гугл - не отвечает никто. Но есть **официальный** источник информации - *man* система.

По первому вопросу. Смотрим *man 3 exit*. Там в третьей строке написано:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

И не надо ни у какого гугла спрашивать - там, зачастую,содержатся совершенно противоречивые советы. Подсказка: в команде *man* второй парамерт означает:

1. Команда Shell
2. Системный вызов (обращение к ядру ОС)
3. Вызов функции из стандартной библиотеки.

По второму вопросу: "что вернёт stat() на каталог?". С точки зрения ФС наиболее распространённых типов (EXT3, EXT4), каталог - это самый обычный файл, в котором содержатся записи определённой структуры. Что бы понять, как отличить регулярный файл от каталога, опять таки смотрим *man 2 stat*. Там даже пример приведён:

```
stat(pathname, &sb);
if ((sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG) {
     /* Handle regular file */
}
```

Ну и третий вопрос - про '.' и '..'. С точки зрения ФС это просто **обозначения** (синонимы) для реальных каталогов - текущего и родительского. Поэтому их обработка ничем не отличается от обработки каталогов, заданных явно.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте `#include <stdlib.h>`

Ошибка в том, что вы не пытаетесь посмотреть в каком заголовочном файле объявлена проблемная функция. Гугл в данном случае дает ответ быстрее, чем вы задаете вопрос.